# How to create a Windows node pool in AKS cluster?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm trying to add a node pool that can run Windows based containers. What I see in Azure portal is a disabled option to select Windows as the OS. The hint says: `Windows node pools require a Windows authentication profile`. I tried googling the possible solution but found nothing.

How can I provide the Windows authentication profile to the existing AKS cluster to make AKS run Windows based containers?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like there is an [open issue](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1005) regarding this situation.

The problem is while creating the cluster for the first time, you didn't provide any `--windows-admin-password` and `--windows-admin-username`. Therefore, when you try to create a new windows node pool that will create VM's, The VM's don't have any `Windows authentication profile`.

If you look at the cluster resource `az aks show` and don't see the Window profile, then you would have to create a new cluster, for example using [AZ CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest):

```
az aks create -g MyResourceGroup -n MyManagedCluster --load-balancer-sku Standard --network-plugin azure --windows-admin-username azure --windows-admin-password 'replacePassword1234$'
```

If you created your cluster using terraform, you can add this section:

```
# Create AKS Cluster
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "akscluster" {

# Code goes here..

  windows_profile {
    admin_username    = "azure"
    admin_password    = "azure"
  }
}
```

Pay attention to this [thread](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/6235) as well.

Comment: If you enable the `--windows-admin-username` can you still do a Linux worker pool as well so you can cover both scenarios?

Comment: @FilBot3 that makes sense, but i never tested it.